# splitting digits from other characters in a string in python

Tags: python, string, list

I have such strings; `'17.'`, `'0,5'`, `',5'`, `'CO2-heidet'`, `'1990ndatel'`, etc. I want to split them as follows: `['17', '.'], ['0', ',', '5'], [',', '5'], ['CO', '2', '-heidet'], ['1990', 'ndatel']`, etc.

How can I do this efficiently in python?

Comment: You probably should show your example "strings" as if they are actually strings: `'17.'`, `'0.5'`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way with [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split):

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: def split_digits(s):
   ...:     return [g for g in re.split(r'(\d+)', s) if g]
   ...: 

In [3]: for s in ['17.', '0,5', ',5', 'CO2-heidet', '1990ndatel']:
   ...:     print(repr(s), 'becomes', split_digits(s))
   ...:     
'17.' becomes ['17', '.']
'0,5' becomes ['0', ',', '5']
',5' becomes [',', '5']
'CO2-heidet' becomes ['CO', '2', '-heidet']
'1990ndatel' becomes ['1990', 'ndatel']
```

Answer (score 4):

You may also use [**`itertools.groupby()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) with *key* as [**`str.isdigit`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) to achieve this as:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> my_list = ['17.', '0,5', ',5', 'CO2-heidet', '1990ndatel']

>>> [[''.join(j) for i, j in groupby(l, str.isdigit)] for l in my_list]
[['17', '.'], ['0', ',', '5'], [',', '5'], ['CO', '2', '-heidet'], ['1990', 'ndatel']]
```